# Map value to key in array object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello I have a object array like below.

```js
dataSource = [
      {
        NAME: "Jan",
        VALUE: 5,
        GRUP: "Grup 1"
      },
      {
        NAME: "Feb",
        VALUE: 15,
        GRUP: "Grup 1"
      },
      {
        NAME: "Mar",
        VALUE: 3,
        GRUP: "Grup 1"
      }
    ]
```

I want to map this to below expected output

```js
[
 {
    Base:"Grup 1",
    Jan:5,
    Feb:15,
    Mar:3
 }
]
```

I tried

```js
let  dataSource = [
          {
            NAME: "Jan",
            VALUE: 5,
            GRUP: "Grup 1"
          },
          {
            NAME: "Feb",
            VALUE: 15,
            GRUP: "Grup 1"
          },
          {
            NAME: "Mar",
            VALUE: 3,
            GRUP: "Grup 1"
          }
        ]

console.log(GetObject(dataSource))

function GetObject(arr){
  return arr.map(el=>
  {
    let obj={};
    obj[el.NAME]=el.VALUE;
    obj.BASE=el.GRUP
    return obj
  }
  );
}
```

but it doesn't give as expected result. It gives me three object array instead of multiple attributes in one object.

How can I map this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the groups in an object:

```js
const groups = {};

for (const data of dataSource) {
    if (!(data.GRUP in groups)) {
        groups[data.GRUP] = {Base: data.GRUP};
    }
    groups[data.GRUP][data.NAME] = data.VALUE;
}

const result = Object.values(groups);
console.log(result);
```